# Bunifu Framework: How do you code a progress bar? (Code below)

Tags: vb.net

Currently I'm coding a project which has a BunifuProgressBar, but I'm having trouble coding it. Basically it says: `'Increment' is not a member of 'BunifuProgressBar'`, any ideas how to fix that issue (Please put the code in the comment section, which will make it so I don't get that error and the prog bar will work.)

CODE:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    BunifuProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    If BunifuProgressBar1.Value = BunifuProgressBar1.Maxium Then
End Sub
```

Regards,

-Zualux

P.S

Like I always say, just comment if you need more information..

Comment: It means there is no member(function) called Increment in the BunifuProgressBar class

Comment: I am aware of that, Suraj, what I'm saying is there anyone who can give me a solution so it WILL work. @SurajS

Comment: Please edit your question indicating the goal you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BunifuProgressBar` does not have a `Increment` method,see the [reference page](https://devtools.bunifu.co.ke/bunifu-ui-winforms-docs/). What it does have is a `Value` property, so what you probably need to do is just:

```
BunifuProgressBar1.Value+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Here](https://devtools.bunifu.co.ke/bunifu-ui-winforms-docs/), It only has

> Value – the progress value 
>   MaximumValue – the maximum allowed progress
>   value ProgressColor – the color of the progress bar 
>   BorderRadius – the roundness of the corners

You probably want to increment Value, set MaximumValue to whatever you want

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
BunifuProgressBar1.Value+=1
If BunifuProgressBar1.Value = BunifuProgressBar1.Maxium Then
```

End Sub